# How to share attribute across multiple class instances?

Tags: python

I need to share single attribute to any object created for a class. How achieve that?

```
class Foo:
    title = None

    def print(self):
        return self.title

if __name__ == "__main__":

    foo1 = Foo()
    foo1.title = "lala"

    foo2 = Foo()
    print(foo2.print())  # lala
```

Comment: Do you mean something like what you get when replacing ``foo1.title = "lala"`` with ``Foo.title = "lala"``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes, property object share to any object.

Comment: And you probably don't mean a literal [``property``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), do you?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i dont know what to call title inside foo class.

but what i want to share that title in foo class. to any foo object created

Comment: I've adjusted your text a bit to match what you have described in the comments. Can you clarify whether you explicitly need something like ``foo1.title = …`` (setting the attribute via an instance) or are you fine with using a different assignment such as ``Foo.title = …``?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the variable in `class Foo` directly like this:

```
    ...
    Foo.title = "lala"
    ...
```

Which produces:

```
class Foo:
    title = None

    def print(self):
        return self.title

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    foo1 = Foo()
    print(foo1.print()) # prints None
    Foo.title = "lala"
    print(foo1.print()) # prints "lala"

    foo2 = Foo()
    print(foo2.print()) # prints "lala"
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can make it [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern);

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

class SingleTon(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'temp'):
            cls.temp = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

        return cls.temp

    def __init__(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'title'):
            self.title = 5

a = SingleTon()
a.title = 'lalala'
print(a.title)

b = SingleTon()
print(b.title)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).